# C# and Crystal Reports - batch printing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, printing, crystal-reports

I have a report (label) that I print and it prints the label one at a time which I believe is because I'm doing it inside a foreach calling the printer and printer and PrintToPrinter.  Does anyone know if I can create the entire datatable then push it to print once so it prints much faster? Right now label by label is quite time consuming.

Here is my code:

```
protected void printKitLabelsAll(string qty)
{
    // Get item, desc from Modata using the order number
    OleDbCommand getKitLabel = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT  CAST(CITEM as char(30) ccsid 37) , CAST(CDESC as char(30) ccsid 37), CAST(FLSTK as char(30) ccsid 37) " +
        $"FROM MODATA WHERE ORDNO = '{orderNumTextBox.Text.ToUpper()}' ORDER BY CITEM", cn);
    OleDbDataAdapter kitDa = new OleDbDataAdapter(getKitLabel);
    DataTable kitDt = new DataTable();
    kitDa.Fill(kitDt);

    // For each row get order, item, desc and write to PDF
    foreach (DataRow row in kitDt.Rows)
    {
        // Get default printer
        OleDbCommand getPrinter = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT CAST(PRINT as char(50) ccsid 37) FROM EMPSET WHERE EMPNO = '{empNo}'", cnDb9);
        cnDb9.Open();
        string printName = getPrinter.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cnDb9.Close();

        // Create Document
        ReportDocument label = new ReportDocument();

        // Load template
        label.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/kitLabel.rpt"));

        // Set parameters
        label.SetParameterValue("order", orderNumTextBox.Text.ToUpper());
        label.SetParameterValue("item", row[0].ToString());
        label.SetParameterValue("desc", row[1].ToString());

        // Print
        label.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "TSC";
        label.PrintToPrinter(int.Parse(qty), false, 0, 0);

        // Dispose label after print
        label.Close();
        label.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the design for the report (in Crystal Designer), remove the Item and Descr parameters.  In other words, the report should simply show all items for the order.
Change your code to feed in just the Order parameter to the report.

Let the Crystal report retrieve data directly from the data source. It can easily get one record for each line item in the order.

Comment: The label needs to show all 3 of those... its a 1x3 label that gets put on all parts they have to see Order, Item, Desc on each label...

Comment: @ksuProgrammer, what MilletSoftware is saying is that, those values shouldn't be parameters. They should be fields in your report. You need to redesign your report to have those fields and then simply load the report and print.

Comment: Can you do that using a datatable when you do the printing or do I have to send it to a report viewer to make that work?